# Pytorch not accessing the GPU's memory

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to run a reinforcement learning algorithm using pytorch, but it keeps telling me that CUDA is out of memory. However, it seems that pytorch is only accessing a tiny amount of my GPU's memory.

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 3.78 MiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 4.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that PyTorch is only accessing a tiny amount of GPU memory, but your PyTorch program accumulatively allocated tensors to the GPU memory, and that 2 MB tensor hits the limitation. Try to use a lower batch size or run the model with half-precision to save the GPU memory.

Answer (score 0):

This command should work for PyTorch to access the GPU memory.

```
> import os os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
```